# gwt-css-background-image-text

Tags: css, gwt, textarea

I have a web-application with gwt.

I have a textare with this css:

```
.progress60{
    font-family: Lucida Sans;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 215px;
    height: 27px;
    background-image: url(images/60.png); 
}
```

I want that the text inside is in the vertical-middle.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use padding on the text like so: `padding-top: 7px;` 7 being (27 - 13)/2.
I'm not sure whether this will add padding to the background image but give it a try!